# How to reset button state to disabled after resetting the form?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

In this form, I've set the submit button to be disabled until form fields are complete. When the submit button is pressed, the preventDefault() runs, and an alert is displayed. On closing that alert, the form resets, but the button state doesn't return to disabled.

```js
//validate form input
function validateForm() {
  let formCheck = document.forms['myForm'].elements;
  let canSubmit = true;

  for (let i = 0; i < formCheck.length; i++) {
    if (formCheck[i].value.length == 0) canSubmit = false;
  } 
  submitThis.disabled = !canSubmit;
}

//prevent form submission, alert if form is submitted, reset form
document.getElementById('submitThis').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Awesomeness! The form will now reset.');
  myForm.reset();
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form input {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

form input[type=submit]:active {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
    <form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="/">
      <h3>My Form</h3>
      <input type="text" id="fName" placeholder="First Name" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
      <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Street Address" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
      <input type="text" id="addCity" placeholder="City" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
      <input type="text" id="addState" placeholder="State" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
      <input type="number" id="addZip" placeholder="Zip Code" onkeyup="validateForm()" />

      <!-- submit form -->
      <input type="submit" id="submitThis" value="Submit" disabled="disabled"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `validateForm` again after the reset:

```js
//validate form input
function validateForm() {
  let formCheck = document.forms['myForm'].elements;
  let canSubmit = true;

  for (let i = 0; i < formCheck.length; i++) {
    if (formCheck[i].value.length == 0) canSubmit = false;
  } 
  submitThis.disabled = !canSubmit;
}

//prevent form submission, alert if form is submitted, reset form
document.getElementById('submitThis').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Awesomeness! The form will now reset.');
  myForm.reset();
  validateForm();
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form input {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

form input[type=submit]:active {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
    <form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="/">
      <h3>My Form</h3>
      <input type="text" id="fName" placeholder="First Name" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
      <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Street Address" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
      <input type="text" id="addCity" placeholder="City" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
      <input type="text" id="addState" placeholder="State" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
      <input type="number" id="addZip" placeholder="Zip Code" onkeyup="validateForm()" />

      <!-- submit form -->
      <input type="submit" id="submitThis" value="Submit" disabled="disabled"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset):

> The **HTMLFormElement.reset()** method restores a form element's default values. This method does the same thing as clicking the form's reset button.
>
> If a form control (such as a reset button) has a name or id of reset it will mask the form's reset method. **It does not reset other attributes in the input, such as `disabled`**.

Thus you will need to set the button to disabled manually after calling form `reset()` like:

```
myForm.reset();
document.getElementById("submitThis").disabled = true;
```

**Demo:**

```js
//validate form input
function validateForm() {
  let formCheck = document.forms['myForm'].elements;
  let canSubmit = true;

  for (let i = 0; i < formCheck.length; i++) {
    if (formCheck[i].value.length == 0) canSubmit = false;
  }
  submitThis.disabled = !canSubmit;
}

//prevent form submission, alert if form is submitted, reset form
document.getElementById('submitThis').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Awesomeness! The form will now reset.');
  myForm.reset();
  document.getElementById("submitThis").disabled = true;
})
```

```css
body{font-family:sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;height:100vh}h2{text-align:center}form{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;height:100vh;flex-direction:column}form input{margin:.5em 0;padding:.5em;border-radius:5px}form input[type=submit]:active{background-color:#00008b;color:#fff}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="/">
  <h3>My Form</h3>
  <input type="text" id="fName" placeholder="First Name" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
  <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Street Address" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
  <input type="text" id="addCity" placeholder="City" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
  <input type="text" id="addState" placeholder="State" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
  <input type="number" id="addZip" placeholder="Zip Code" onkeyup="validateForm()" />

  <!-- submit form -->
  <input type="submit" id="submitThis" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `validateForm` after submitting the form

```js
function validateForm() {
  let formCheck = document.forms['myForm'].elements;
  let canSubmit = true;

  for (let i = 0; i < formCheck.length; i++) {
    if (formCheck[i].value.length == 0) canSubmit = false;
  }
  submitThis.disabled = !canSubmit;
}

//prevent form submission, alert if form is submitted, reset form
document.getElementById('submitThis').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Awesomeness! The form will now reset.');
  myForm.reset();
  validateForm(); // changed here
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form input {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

form input[type=submit]:active {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="/">
  <h3>My Form</h3>
  <input type="text" id="fName" placeholder="First Name" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
  <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Street Address" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
  <input type="text" id="addCity" placeholder="City" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
  <input type="text" id="addState" placeholder="State" onkeyup="validateForm()" />
  <input type="number" id="addZip" placeholder="Zip Code" onkeyup="validateForm()" />

  <!-- submit form -->
  <input type="submit" id="submitThis" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```